# How to convert a signed int to its hex representation on nbBits, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

For instance : -78_base10 on 8 bits is 0xB2

The pseudo-algorithm says : "-A =/A+1"

For instance :

- -78 => 78 => 01001110
- Then apply 'bar' : 01001110 => 10110001
- Then '+1' : 10110001 + 1 = 10110010
- convert in hexa : 0xB2

How to get the result nicely in Ruby (with or without this 'algorithm').

Comment: If 'bar' is just the one's complement function, please write so.

Comment: @Qerub The algorithm is one's complement. 'bar' is just a bitwise inversion.

Comment: @AllanNørgaard Ones' complement *is* bitwise inversion. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement.

Comment: @Qerub Yes of course it is. What I should have written is, that the algorithm is two's complement. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
def signed_int_to_hex(n)
  "0x%X" % (n % 2 ** 8)
end

signed_int_to_hex(-78) #=> "0xB2"
```

Comment: Interesting, what was that downvote for, 1 month after the answer got accepted?

Answer (score 0):

```
((-78) % 2 ** 8).to_s(16)
# => "b2"
```